# Not able to claim rewards

Tags: nodeos, cleos, block-producer

I am running my private chain with 3 BPs,

I have created 1000000.0000 tokens,
I have issued 100000.0000 tokens,
and run the further steps for setting up the chain,

I voted all the BPs with 10-15 accounts to start producing the blocks
Here, I wanted to mention one thing is for start producing the blocks BP must have at least 15% stake vote, so All BPs have 15% of stake tokens, but they are not started producing the blocks.

When I try to claim the rewards with

> cleos system claimrewards BP_NAME

then I am getting this type of error.

> Error 3050003: alaio_assert_message assertion failure
>
> Error Details:
>
> assertion failure with message: cannot claim rewards until the chain is activated (at least 15% of all tokens participate in voting)
>
> pending console output:

Answer (score 0):

The amount of `min_activated_stake` is hard-coded rather than proportional to your issuing token. [[link]](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/897d88c68599db3cdbf8d60412c397f429455d84/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L66)

15% here means 15% of total tokens. Voted weight on each BP doesn't matter. On EOS mainnet, the initial amount of token is 1B, so min_activated_stake is set to 150M.

Comment: Thanks! @conr2d So I have issued 100000.0000 that means 15% of 100000.0000 is 15000 right? and I guess it won't affect anywhere right? (because I am issuing less amount of tokens)

Comment: There are two kinds of reward (bpay, _block pay_, for block production, vpay, _voting pay_, for being voted). Voting pay less than 100.0000 per day is ignored. You issued less token, but block pay and voting pay is determined by inflation amount. If you want to make voting pay works with your configuration, `min_pervote_daily_pay` should be adjusted to less. [link](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L68)